# How can we identify time section in datetime flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, utc

I will receive DateTime in UTC format from API and I need to convert the DateTime to local time zone based on the condition.

We have toLocal() method to change the time based on the device time zone.

```
condition: 23-4-2021  // no need to change it to toLocal()
           23-4-2021 00:00:00 // no need to change it to toLocal()
           23-4-2021 10:30:34 // need to change it to toLocal()
```

If we have time in the DateTime then only we have to change it in local time.

```
DateTime utcToDateTimeLocal(DateTime value) {
  return value.toLocal();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say time section?

Comment: If I receive correct time in datetime  (not 00:00:00) from API then I have to change as local time otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

```
  DateTime utcToDateTimeLocal(DateTime value)  {

    var dateFormat =
    DateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm a"); // you can change the format here
    var utcDate =
    dateFormat.format(DateTime.parse(value.toString())); // pass the UTC time here
    var localDate = dateFormat.parse(utcDate, true).toLocal().toString();
    return DateTime.parse(localDate);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe ?

```dart
DateTime utcToDateTimeLocal(DateTime value) {
  if (value.hour!=0 || value.minute!=0 || value.second!=0){
     return value.toLocal();
  }
 return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is quick solution that work for me.**
You can get time (or any format) by DateFormat class

In your case
dateTime = '23-4-2021 10:30:34'

```
final format = DateFormat('HH:mm a');
final clockString = format.format(dateTime);
```

you will get // 10:30 AM